# A shopkeeper purchased goods using a false balance weighing ..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A shopkeeper purchased goods using a false balance weighing $19$% more and sells goods using another false balance weighing $15$% less. Find his profit percentage.

My Attempt: 
 he cheats $19$% while buying, which means he spends Rs $100$ for goods which are worth Rs. $119$.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             he cheats $15$% on selling, which means he sold goods worth Rs $100$ for Rs $115$. Overall, he sold goods worth Rs $1$ for Rs $\frac{115}{100}$. So he sold goods worth Rs $115$ for Rs $132.25$   $$\text{profit } = 132.25-100=32.5 \\ \text{profit %} = \frac{32.5}{100}*100 = 32.5\%$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the shopkeeper's actions.  If he wants to buy 10kg of mangoes, he puts them on a scale that weighs them at 11.9 kg?  Then, when he sells those same mangoes, he puts them on a scale that weighs them at 8.5kg?  It seems like he loses money on both transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that You meant, that shopkeeper used weightings that weight 19% more / 15% less. Because if he would use weighings showing 19% more / 15% less, he would loose money on every transaction.

Here is the answer for a salesman using prepared weightings (119g weighting and 85g weighting marked as 100g weightings)

1. First he buys 119% of goods paying 100% of the real prize. It means, that every unit of goods was bougth by salesman for $\frac{100}{119} \approx 84\%$ of it's real prize.
2. Then salesman sells $85\%$ goods for 100% of it's real prize. So every unit of goods is sold for $\frac{100}{85}\approx 118\%$ of it's real prize
3. On each unit of goods salesman earns $(\frac{100}{85}-\frac{100}{119})\approx 34\%$ of it's real prize
4. Profit is then $\frac{\frac{100}{85}-\frac{100}{119}}{\frac{100}{119}} =  \frac{119}{85}-1 = .4 = 40\%$

Comment: The way you describe it, the first balance creates 19% more goods which are weightless.  Still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No. The first balance says, that 119g of goods is described by salesman as 100g, because his '100g weghting' is actually 119g weighting. So he buys 119g of goods in prize of 100g.

Comment: I agree that a balance that did that would lead to the answer you give.  But why would a balance that did that be described as "weighing 19% more"? The balance you describe shows a weight that is 16% *less* than the actual weight.